# Inject a Map of Interface Implementations Keyed by Enum Values

Tags: java, dependency-injection, playframework, guice

I am using Java 8 with a Play framework. My goal is to inject a map whose keys are enum values and values are implementations of a specific interface.

Here is my enum:

```
public enum Service {

    HTML("html"), TEXT("txt");

    private String serviceId;
    Service(String serviceId) { this.serviceId = serviceId; }

}
```

I have `Executable` interface

```
public interface Executable { void execute(); }
```

and two classes that implement it:

```
public class HtmlWorker implements Executable { ... } 
public class TextWorker implements Executable { ... }
```

I would like to be able to inject  `Map<Service, Executable> serviceMap` so I can have access to a specific implementation using a `Service` key:

```
public class Processor {

  @Inject
  Map<Service, Executable> serviceMap;

  public void doStuff() {
      Executable htmlService = this.serviceMap.get(Service.HTML);
      Executable textService = this.serviceMap.get(Service.TEXT);
      // do more stuff
  }
}
```

I added bindings to the module class:

```
public class AppModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        MapBinder<Service, Executable> serviceBinder = MapBinder
          .newMapBinder(binder(), Service.class, Executable.class);

        serviceBinder.addBinding(Service.HtmlService).to(HtmlWorker.class);
        serviceBinder.addBinding(Service.TextService).to(TextWorker.class);

    }
```

The problem is that `serviceMap` is never injected and it is always `null` inside `Processor`. What am I missing?

Comment: How and where are you `@Inject Processor`?

Comment: ...and if you aren't injecting Processor but creating it by invoking `new Processor()`, that is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [MapBinder](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html) documentation the `MapBinder.addBinding` should take the map's key.

As far as concerning your provided example what about changing `AbstractModule`'s code from:

```
serviceBinder.addBinding(Service.HtmlService).to(HtmlWorker.class);
serviceBinder.addBinding(Service.TextService).to(TextWorker.class);
```

to

```
serviceBinder.addBinding(Service.HTML).to(HtmlWorker.class); // <-- see the enum constant here?
serviceBinder.addBinding(Service.TEXT).to(TextWorker.class);
```

Anyway I don't know where the class `Service.HtmlService` in your example comes from since you didn't state it anywhere.